# possessive pronoun "its" with noun

Tags: usage, nouns, dummy-pronouns

Is the following [sentence](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=MvEmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT93&lpg=PT93&dq=%22excludes+its+not%22&source=bl&ots=Q1UG3BWwuf&sig=AboBFwmZ1UOnEJy0YbMsfUDDFrE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ5ZOSuafNAhUMu48KHeC0C0IQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22excludes%20its%20not%22&f=false), which uses possessive pronoun  "its" without noun, correct?

> Affirming something's being white excludes denying it, because something's being white excludes ***its*** not being white.

This [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8YrA9xNZz7QC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22that+excludes+its%22&source=bl&ots=fdFBTlLRFY&sig=Vft8-9F5L0JQ2t1POH5P8qjSrAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv1p62oanNAhWEvY8KHXa0B4EQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22that%20excludes%20its%22&f=false), for example, uses the noun "material truth" after "its"

> Denying an idea is having another idea that excludes **its material truth**.

It would more helpful if anyone interpret with apt examples.

**EDIT:** The word "plural" has been changed "possessive". Apology for my mistake.

Comment: Fighting the urge to quote Heinlein... Could you explain what you mean by 'without noun'? In the first sentence the noun is 'Something' in the second it's 'idea'

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not believe that the word *it* can be plural.

In the two examples you provide, *its* is the possessive form of *it*. There is another word, *it's*. "It's" is a contraction of "it" and "is".

So in the firs example, (not being white) **is acting** as a noun and it belongs to *it*:

> something's being white excludes the possibility of it (the thing) not being white

In the second example, the (material truth) belongs to *it*:

> material truth of it (that original idea)

Comment: The word "plural" has been changed "possessive". Apology for my mistake.

Comment: My answer still stands. I can provide more examples if you request.

Comment: please, I need the answer for "possessive" not for "plural".

Comment: Yes, my answer is about "possessive" not "plural". I don't think "plural" exists.

Comment: I mean I need the **examples** for "possessive" not for "plural".

Comment: Oh! Ok, give me a moment.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you modify the answer completely according to the question.

Comment: I mean, I think my answer does address your questions. But you think it doesn't, so what exactly is your question? You are dealing with some abstract concepts in those sentences. Do you want an interpretation of those sentences or an explanation of the use of "it"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41188/discussion-between-aryf-and-probablyme).

Comment: I think it's preferable to see "not being white" is a gerund-participial clause, rather than as an expression 'acting as a noun'.

Comment: @BillJ Where can I learn more about this? Is there a textbook you recommend?